# creating a new user account with the least privileges in windows 7

Tags: uac, privileges

i'm just wondering how can i create a normal user account which can login without a password and can access only to the main partition usually named (C:) supposing that we have another partition named (D:). all this using cmd

Comment: Create a new user group with the permissions you want the create a user in that group

Comment: @Ramhound i've searched in many websites but none of them explain how to set privilegs for a group,they only talk about creating or deleting a group which is very easy
can you show me where to begin . thanks :)

Comment: You need help setting up a user group permissions

Comment: exactly a group of normal users and who can access only C:

Comment: What permissions have you provided this new user group exactly?

Comment: in fact i look how to grant these permissions to the group using windows shell( i'm just a beginner). i believe they're not like GNU/Linux Shell commands
can you give an example of such commands 
thank you again for your help i really appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preliminary steps

1. Open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7).
2. Type or paste the following command after replacing `NewUser` with the name you want to use. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you're done.

   ```
   net user "NewUser" "" /add
   ```

   By default new user accounts are always created as standard users (i.e. non-admin). The specified password is empty.
3. Log on with the new account, and then log off. This is just to ensure the profile gets initialized.

### Hide and prevent access to any drive but C: from My Computer

Back to the command prompt, type or paste the following commands. Make sure to replace all `NewUser` with the actual account name, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> each time.

```
reg load "HKU\NewUser" "%SystemDrive%\Users\NewUser\NTUSER.DAT"
reg add "HKU\NewUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" /v "NoDrives" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x3fffffb /f
reg add "HKU\NewUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" /v "NoViewOnDrive" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x3fffffb /f
reg unload "HKU\NewUser"
```

### Deny access to drives and all their subfolders

1. Type or paste the commands below. Replace `NewUser` with the account name, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   takeown /f D: /a
   icacls D: /deny "NewUser":(OI)(CI)(F)
   ```
2. Repeat step 1 for any other drive you want to restrict by replacing `D:` with the actual letter.

### References

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)
- [Using Group Policy Objects to hide specified drives](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231289/en-us)
- [Prevent access to drives from My Computer](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2663)